# jQuery event triggering on all listeners

Tags: jquery

I have a custom event I've made which I would like to trigger at some point with no relevance to selection.

I.E - I would like to do something that would behave as running

```
$("*").trigger('customEvent');
```

But jQuery documentation warns that using the universal selector is very slow.
Is there a way to trigger all the object that are bound to a specific event without having to use the universal selector `$("*")`?

Thanks!

P.S - I'm currently using a specific `class` called `custom_event_listener` and use `$('.custom_event_listener').trigger('customEvent')` to avoid using a universal selector. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid the use of a `class`.

Comment: Can't you let this event bubble and capture it at a higher level?

Comment: So, you want to do something to all elements, but not using a select all elements. There's gotta be another way you can narrow the selection down, but we can't know what it is without more info on what you're doing.

Comment: @Andre I'm not sure what that means. sort of a newbie in jQuery. I'll google 'bubble jQuery events' and see if it helps.

Comment: @Zirak The only information I have regarding the selection is "People who have bound on 'customEvent'". Is there maybe a selector that uses this data?

Comment: Ben, I think Nick Craver's answer solves your problem. Anyway, bubbling is how javascript (not jQuery) event propagates. You should read about it, it's very important to know when dealing with events. Cheers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can trigger an event on everything that has a handler bound like this:

```
$.event.trigger('customEvent');
```

[This loops through `$.cache` to find what actually has a handler, then fires on those elements](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L322-335)...rather than just finding *every* element and firing the event on each one.

Comment: Best answer so far. If I don't get an answer that narrows it down even further I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: This is undocumented and deprecated: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/935eb19d87063ec30b717b3d45368d3c73cb591d/jquery-migrate.js#L481