# How to trigger events on all elements

Tags: jquery

I want to use custom events in my J-Query website. Now I'm not sure which one is the best way to trigger a custom event on all elements attached to this event.

An example could be more clarifying here: Basically I could use

```
$('#id').trigger('customevent');
```

I don't want the triggering element to have to know all elements attached to the event. So I could use

```
$('*').trigger('customevent');
```

which would hopefully do what I want. But I'm afraid that this way has some performance issues.

Another way I was thinking about is using a class. All elements attached to the event could add this class to themselves. Then I can use this class as selector. However, all this smells like workaround.

I really hope that somebody knows an usual way to solve my problem.

Comment: Just found the answer by myself:

    $.event.trigger('customevent');

But I'm not allowed to answer my question. Doubtful limitation...

Comment: I think you have to wait some hours.... but then you can add your answer. *Edit:* Actually it's a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery event triggering on all listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860146/jquery-event-triggering-on-all-listeners)

Comment: You are right, its a duplicate. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the answer by myself (which is now **deprecated**, see comment below):

```
$.event.trigger('customevent');
```

Comment: This is undocumented and deprecated: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/935eb19d87063ec30b717b3d45368d3c73cb591d/jquery-migrate.js#L481

Comment: Not sure if it is an appropriate downvote reason because a function became deprecated three years after it was perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. Before that, it was incorrect (irrespective of if it was correct at the time or not), thus the downvote. I've removed the downvote.