# Can't listen to global event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860146/jquery-event-triggering-on-all-listeners) pointed out that it should be possible to trigger an event on all listning objects using:

```
$.event.trigger('customEvent');
```

However this does not seem to work for me in an example like:

```
$('body').bind('customEvent', function(){ alert('Working!'); });
```

Am I doing something completely wrong, or has this great functionality been disabled?

Comment: any error displayed in Developer Console ?

Comment: Works for me (version 1.7.1)

Comment: It seems to work in until jQuery 1.8.3: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3Grvn/. Does not work anymore in jQuery 1.9+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that functionality has been removed. Browsing through the tags I managed to find [this TODO in v1.8b1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8b1/src/event.js#L263):

> // TODO: Stop taunting the data cache; remove global events and always attach to document

And it was removed as of [v1.9.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.0/src/event.js).

There is nothing stopping you from implementing it based on the old source code [here (v1.6.2)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L322-335), but it looks like it was doing naughty things talking to `jQuery.cache` so it's probably best to live without it or come up with another solution.

```
$('*').trigger('customEvent');
```

Perhaps? ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/5hEgy/))

Or a more efficient approach of keeping track of each subscription and calling `.trigger()` on that.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/gshsu/)

```
var customSubs;

$.fn.subscribeCustom = function (fn) {
    this.on('customEvent', fn);
    if (!customSubs)
        customSubs = this;
    else
        customSubs = customSubs.add(this);
};

$('span').subscribeCustom(function () {
    alert('span!');
});
$('div').subscribeCustom(function () {
    alert('div!');
});

customSubs.trigger('customEvent');
```

Comment: That selector is killing me

Comment: I don't like the universal selector either, that's why I wanted to use this. But since it has been removed, I'll just revert to attaching to the document then. Thanks for the information!