# Javascript custom events - trigger to all listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create customEvent. For example i have some elements,and every one is listening to this event. When i click on one of them i want to trigger my customEvent. How to make this?

Example:

```
var customEvent = new Event('customEvent');

var $ul = $('ul');

var $markers = $('#map').find('.markers');

// UL>LI
$ul.delegate('click', 'li', function(){
    customEvent.trigger();
});

$ul.delegate('customEvent', 'li', function(){
    $ul.find('li').removeClass("active");

});

// MAP MARKERS
$markers.on('click', 'li', function(){
    customEvent.trigger();
});

$markers.on('customEvent', function(){
    // do sth
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Its simple, you need to use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

*Script*

```
ele.on('click', function() {  
      $(this).trigger('customEvent');
      //Or, $(this).trigger(customEvent); 
});
```

Comment: Will it trigger this event only on this element or on all listeners?

Comment: It will trigger on only current element, if you want to trigger on all element use `ele.trigger('customEvent');`

Comment: But i have many diffrence elements, im not stroing them into one variable. I can use ele.trigger(), but i will need to write it  ele1.trigger(), ele2.trigger(). I dont want do that. Is it posible to trigger event as self?

Comment: @Sko You should provide concrete sample on what is your expected behaviour. Why would you want to trigger a custom event if it is not specific to any element but all? Why not calling a function? Does it help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6860214/1414562?

Comment: @Sko i see `$.event.trigger('customEvent');` no more working for jq 1.9+